# Photoshop CS6. Disable pixel grid appearance when selecting pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-grid

Is it possible, to disable appearance of pixel grid, when selecting pixels (e.g. use of region selection, magic wand, lasso and other selection tools)? I'm work with pixel art, and I always turn this grid to off, and when want to move region of pixels, that grid appears, which not very comfortable (especially when need to select color surrounded with almost same looking colors. That grid is too contrast, and makes problem with recognizing color that I need).

Answer (score 6):

CMD+H hide the extras and may not be the ideal solution.
Try disable the pixel grid by clicking **View > Show > Pixel Grid**

Comment: The problem of this (and its shortcut Ctrl+H) is that once you do another selection the grid will reaper again.

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> when I am using the patch tool.  First I use the patch tool to say darken down an area that is bright by finding an area on the brighter part and patching it to a darker area. I then have marching ants on my Image My next step is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>... I then go to Edit Fade patch selection with this you can then use the slider to blend the selection that you applied that was dark into the area that is lighter. Or visa versa.

Comment: I know that shortcut, and I use it all time, but I'm talking about disabling automatic activation of grid while selecting. The grid is automatically turns on, if I use any selection tool, even if grid turned off.

Comment: ok I misunderstood your question. I've used PS for several years and never heard it has such function like what you described. It's sounds reasonable because these "ant lines" appear again to remind you are working within certain region. If triggering some toggle and it never shows again, most people will forget that(I experienced this in other software). So I'm using ctrl-H every time when i want to hide these annoying lines.

Answer (score 0):

**View** > **Show** > **Show extra options** > uncheck **Grid** & **Pixel Grid** > **OK** > Close Photoshop > Open again.

That's all.